# Extract part of line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically this opens the file pw.txt which contains my passwords listed like this:

Service: (...)

Username: (...)

Password: (...)

The following method is supposed to print all service names (obviously) but without the "Service:".
What can I do to make this work?

```
def print_all_service_names():
    print("\nAvailable Services:\n")
    file = open('/home/manos/Documents/python/resources_py/pw.txt',  'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'Service' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Could you please describe your problem? It doesn't make much sense!

Comment: Also please do add the sample contents of the file you are using

Comment: Take a look at the str.split() method in order to split up a string into a list of parts.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's now understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wish to remove `'Service'` from each line. That can be done as so. I also cleaned a bit up in the way you read from a file.

Generally, you should use the `with` statement when reading from file, as that automatically takes care of closing the file again after you've finished working with it

```py
def print_all_service_names():
    print("\nAvailable Services:\n")
    with open('/home/manos/Documents/python/resources_py/pw.txt',  'r') as fo:
        for line in fo:
            if 'Service' in line:
                # Remove "Service" from your string, by replacing with empty string
                out = line.replace('Service', '')  
                out = out.strip()  # Remove any trailing whitespace
                print(out)
```